Does Allah love me?
I prayed several times, read Quran, perform zhikr in other to ensure that am close to almighty Allah but non of my prayers was answered am frustrated as things are continuing to be more difficult to me than ever and responsibility keeps increasing. As am writing now am the only person who is healthy in my family as two of my brothers are sick having a kind of brain disorder my mum was retired and our father is death 12 years ago am just 32 but right now the responsibility over me is beyond my ability am a graduate of civil engineering but not employed yet and even the local job in the society seems to be difficult for me to have as no one was looking for my service,I prayed keeps praying and nothing changes

Really sorry I can not give any help or advice, but it reminds me of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_(biblical_figure) .

The more you be in trouble, and be patient, the greater would be the reward. We are told in Ahadeeth that people in trouble in Dunya when they find out in the Day what rewards are kept for them, they wish if they could have had tolerated more troubles in Dunya so that their reward was greater now.
Also, we are told that the prophets PBUT sent to a group of people have always tolerated more problems than what their people were confronted with, and that the problems of the holy prophet Muhammad PBUHH was the greatest of all. Also, every time that Allah wants something good for a group of people, first put them in troubles, as so much that they truly cry to Allah, as Allah has described Himself as: "أَمَّنْ يُجِيبُ الْمُضْطَرَّ إِذَا دَعَاهُ وَ يَكْشِفُ السُّوءَ" which reads "Or, Who listens to the distressed when it calls on Him, and Who relieves its suffering". But how much this suffering would be depends and vary from case to case, but in another verse Allah has described the situation of the companions of the prophets this way:

أَمْ حَسِبْتُمْ أَنْ تَدْخُلُوا الْجَنَّةَ وَ لَمَّا يَأْتِكُمْ مَثَلُ الَّذِينَ خَلَوْا مِنْ قَبْلِكُمْ مَسَّتْهُمُ الْبَأْسَاءُ وَ الضَّرَّاءُ وَ زُلْزِلُوا حَتَّيٰ يَقُولَ الرَّسُولُ وَ الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا مَعَهُ مَتَيٰ نَصْرُ اللَّهِ أَلَا إِنَّ نَصْرَ اللَّهِ قَرِيبٌ
Or do ye think that ye shall enter the Garden (of bliss) without such (trials) as came to those who passed away before you? they encountered suffering and adversity, and were so shaken in spirit that even the Messenger and those of faith who were with him cried: 'When (will come) the help of Allah?' Ah! Verily, the help of Allah is (always) near!

Be warned also that committing suicide will never set you free of troubles, but instead opens troubles of eternity to you, I hope it never happens. If you are so much tired of all the troubles you have mention that Allah has statedL

لَقَدْ خَلَقْنَا الْإِنْسَانَ فِي كَبَدٍ ... أَلَمْ ... هَدَيْنَاهُ النَّجْدَيْنِ . فَلَا اقْتَحَمَ الْعَقَبَةَ . وَ مَا أَدْرَاكَ مَا الْعَقَبَةُ
Verily We have created man into toil and struggle ... Have We not ... shown him the two ways? But he hath made no haste on the path that is steep. And what will explain to thee the path that is steep?

So that you should think of your troubles as a steep part of your life path, which is not going to last for ever. Remembering this from times to times will probably make it simpler for you to pass the way with your faith all safe.
And last but by no means least, think of people now in Gaza, and you will suddenly find yourself living a life full of givings from Allah, that you should be thankful for every day and night. Instead of looking at those who seems to have an easy and happy life, see those who are happy with all the problems that they have and are probably more tremendous than yours. Most of the times, the problem is rooted in our very point of view, the perspective we see the life trough, the expectations we have due to fantasy dreams of ourselves, suffering from being far from our dreams when we confront a problem, even if a small one. If so, change your glasses and choose a more mature realistic one ... If you see Allah everywhere with you (as He said "هُوَ مَعَكُمْ أَيْنَ مَا كُنْتُمْ وَ اللَّهُ بِمَا تَعْمَلُونَ بَصِيرٌ"), then you can tolerate any and every difficulty, as you remember all these are some scenarios on a scene called Dunya and we are all performing our defined roles, all temporary, and that our real life is off the scene ... and the real richest of us is those who are more pious in Dunya, whatsoever our roles are ... (إِنَّ أَكْرَمَكُمْ عِنْدَ اللَّهِ أَتْقَاكُمْ)
